# How to Set HTTPS proxy in Ferdi

Tags: https

How can set HTTP (SSL) proxy in programs ?
I want to use Nordvpn https proxy in programs. When I use NordVPN HTTP proxy in Ferdi in this format -
Proxy Host/IP : http://name.nordvpn.com
Port : 80
Username: Something
Password: Something

It works but when I use HTTPS proxy from NordVPN in this format.
Proxy Host/IP : https://name.nordvpn.com
Port : 80
Username: Something
Password: Something
It show error: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

I got my servers from https://nordvpn.com/servers/tools/
and choosed below options
Advanced Option>P2P and HTTP Proxy for HTTP and HTTP SSL for HTTPS

Any Idea how can I use HTTPS proxy in ferdi and any mistake in above HTTPS format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number used by the NordVPN HTTP SSL proxy is 89.

It's not published anywhere on their website, and I don't know why. Someone on Reddit figured it out by looking through the code of their browser plugin. I had the a similar problem and this port works for me.